# Deliver to a client an encrypted c code with unencrypted h file

Tags: c, compilation, coding-style

I wonder if it is possible to deliver to our client an encrypted c file with an unencrypted h file, so the customer can change only the h file as he wishes. How should I do this?

Thanks in advance

Alan Blumenstein

Comment: Are you saying the client needs to be able to build the code? Otherwise you just compile into a library and deliver both the binary and the headers. That's the normal way to package a non-source release.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]" to learn how this site works. -- This seems to be an [X-Y-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you really want to achieve?

Comment: if client changes .h file then compiled C file will not usable.

Comment: Yes, the client should be able to change the h file. But just some defines

Comment: @alanblu if you want your client to be able to change some defines and recompile the whole program you will probably have to obfuscate it, or to generate every single possible binary according to the defines, I don't think there's any other way

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can obfuscate the code:

```
  /* After C++ Code Obfuscating */

  #include <sys/types.h>
  #include <sys/param.h>
  #include <sys/socket.h>
  #include <netinet/in.h>
  #include <arpa/inet.h>
  #include <ctype.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include "gpsd_config.h"
  #include "bsd-base64.h"
  #define Assert(Cond) if (!(Cond)) abort()
  static const char Base64[]=
  "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";static
  const char Pad64='=';int b64_ntop(u_char const*src,size_t srclength,char*target
  ,size_t targsize){size_t datalength=0;u_char input[3];u_char output[4];size_t i
  ;while(2<srclength){input[0]=*src++;input[1]=*src++;input[2]=*src++;srclength-=
  3;output[0]=input[0]>>2;output[1]=((input[0]&0x03)<<4)+(input[1]>>4);output[2]=
  ((input[1]&0x0f)<<2)+(input[2]>>6);output[3]=input[2]&0x3f;Assert(output[0]<64)
  ;Assert(output[1]<64);Assert(output[2]<64);Assert(output[3]<64);if(datalength+4
  >targsize)return(-1);target[datalength++]=Base64[output[0]];target[datalength++
  ]=Base64[output[1]];target[datalength++]=Base64[output[2]];target[datalength++]
  =Base64[output[3]];}if(0!=srclength){input[0]=input[1]=input[2]='\0';for(i=0;i<
  srclength;i++)input[i]=*src++;output[0]=input[0]>>2;output[1]=((input[0]&0x03)
  <<4)+(input[1]>>4);output[2]=((input[1]&0x0f)<<2)+(input[2]>>6);Assert(output[0
  ]<64);Assert(output[1]<64);Assert(output[2]<64);if(datalength+4>targsize)return
  (-1);target[datalength++]=Base64[output[0]];target[datalength++]=Base64[output[
  1]];if(srclength==1)target[datalength++]=Pad64;else target[datalength++]=Base64
  [output[2]];target[datalength++]=Pad64;}if(datalength>=targsize)return(-1);
  target[datalength]='\0';return(datalength);}int b64_pton(char const*src,u_char*
  target,size_t targsize){size_t tarindex;int state,ch;char*pos;state=0;tarindex=
  0;while((ch=*src++)!='\0'){if(isspace(ch))continue;if(ch==Pad64)break;if((pos=
  strchr(Base64,ch))==NULL)return(-1);switch(state){case 0:if(target){if(tarindex
  >=targsize)return(-1);target[tarindex]=(pos-Base64)<<2;}state=1;break;case 1:if
  (target){if(tarindex+1>=targsize)return(-1);target[tarindex]|=(pos-Base64)>>4;
  target[tarindex+1]=((pos-Base64)&0x0f)<<4;}tarindex++;state=2;break;case 2:if(
  target){if(tarindex+1>=targsize)return(-1);target[tarindex]|=(pos-Base64)>>2;
  target[tarindex+1]=((pos-Base64)&0x03)<<6;}tarindex++;state=3;break;case 3:if(
  target){if(tarindex>=targsize)return(-1);target[tarindex]|=(pos-Base64);}
  tarindex++;state=0;break;}}if(ch==Pad64){ch=*src++;switch(state){case 0:case 1:
  return(-1);case 2:for(;ch!='\0';ch=*src++)if(!isspace(ch))break;if(ch!=Pad64)
  return(-1);ch=*src++;case 3:for(;ch!='\0';ch=*src++)if(!isspace(ch))return(-1);
  if(target!=0&&target[tarindex]!=0)return(-1);}}else{if(state!=0)return(-1);}
  return(tarindex);}
```

or

```
 #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  int main(int a,char**A){FILE*B;typedef unsigned long C;C b[8];if(!(a==7&&(B=
  fopen(1[A],"rb"))))return 1;for(7[b]=0;7[b]<5;7[b]++)b[7[b]]=strtoul(A[2+7[b]],
  0,16-!7[b]*6);5[b]=3[b];while((6[b]=getc(B))!=(C)-1){if(2[b])for(7[b]=0;7[b]<4;
  7[b]++)if(((6[b]>>7[b])^(6[b]>>(7-7[b])))&1)6[b]^=(1<<7[b])^(1<<(7-7[b]));5[b]
  ^=6[b]<<(0[b]-8);for(7[b]=0;7[b]<8;7[b]++)if((5[b]>>(0[b]-1))&1)5[b]=(5[b]<<1)^
  1[b];else 5[b]<<=1;}5[b]&=((((C)1<<(0[b]-1))-1)<<1)|1;if(2[b])for(7[b]=0;7[b]<(
  0[b]>>1);7[b]++)if(((5[b]>>7[b])^(5[b]>>(0[b]-1-7[b])))&1)5[b]^=((C)1<<7[b])^((
  C)1<<(0[b]-1-7[b]));5[b]^=4[b];fclose(B);printf("%0*lX\n",(int)(0[b]+3)>>2,5[b]
  );return 0;}
```

But if I am your client and see this kind of sources supplied I would start to look for another contractor.

Comment: I could thing about it but I dont see it really usefull even for me to mantein it after haha.